# Calculate diff of 2 excel sheets and merge the data for delta

Tags: excel

I have one excel with 3 columns as id, name and mail id and second excel with columns id, token and access date. I want to calculate
the delta of two excels based on column 1, 'id' i,e all the rows from excel 1 that do not have entry in excel 2 based on id. And the final sheet
with the diff should contain the merged data from both the excels i.e id, name , mail id, token and access date.  please suugest.

Comment: Use the VLOOKUP function: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1

Comment: Can you please write a small example? The solution to your problems seems easy, but without a numeric example it is very hard to show you how to do it.